# How do I add a namespace to only ref elements in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an XElement which contains the content that I want. However, I want to add a namespace prefix to only the ref elements. Is this possible in C#?

For example, the original XML looks like this:

```
<Root>
  <Element1 />
  <Element2 />
  <Element3>
    <Element3_Child1 />
    <Element3_Child2 />
  </Element3>
  <Element4 />
  <Element5>
    <Element5_Child1>
       <Element5_Child1_Child51 />
    </Element5_Child1>
  </Element5>
</Root>
```

I want to add a namespace prefix, so that the XML looks as below

```
<Root>
  <Element1 />
  <Element2 />
  <ns:Element3>
    <Element3_Child1 />
    <Element3_Child2 />
  </Element3>
  <Element4 />
  <ns:Element5>
    <ns:Element5_Child1>
       <Element5_Child1_Child51 />
    </Element5_Child1>
  </Element5>
</Root>
```

Comment: What are 'the ref elements' ?

Comment: For example, my XML looks like
<Root>

Comment: Don't put that in a comment, add sample XML to the question. And format it as code ( `{}` button)

Comment: The element which you want is invalid - the namespace `ns` needs to be declared somewhere. Can you post exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @carlosfigueira: I think that is what the OP wants to know - *How to define the namespace?*

Answer (score 0):

You can do as stated here : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

```
<root
    xmlns:foo="http://www.example.org/foo"
    xmlns:bar="http://www.example.org/bar">
```

However, I'm pretty sure you'll need a valid URI and that you can't "fake" one. Otherwise, the namespace will be invalid. But you can test and let us know.